# Db queries of OIM

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

1. DB query to check Account status of the user
2. DB query to check Entitlement status of the user
3. DB query to check Role and Access Policy mapping.

Please let me know if anyone have these queries?

Comment: This is very unclear, what are you trying to accomplish here ? You should consider adding more information and maybe read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: I am new to this site, yes I will surely work through your suggestions. Thanks ,

Comment: It's fine, that's why we are helping you with your question, Welcome to Stackoverflow !

Answer (score 6):

1. For Account status

   ```
   SELECT usr.usr_login,obj.obj_name,ost.ost_status 
   FROM orc, usr, obj, oiu, ost, obi WHERE orc.orc_key = oiu.orc_key AND  oiu.usr_key = usr.usr_key AND oiu.ost_key = ost.ost_key 
   AND oiu.obi_key = obi.obi_key AND obi.obj_key = obj.obj_key AND obj.obj_name='ABC' order by usr.usr_login
   ```
2. Entitlement status of the user

   ```
   select usr.usr_login,ENT_LIST.ent_display_name,
   ENT_LIST.ent_value,ENT_ASSIGN.ent_status 
   from ENT_ASSIGN, usr, ENT_LIST where usr.usr_key = ent_assign.usr_key and 
   ENT_LIST.ent_list_key = ENT_ASSIGN.ent_list_key 
   and ENT_LIST.ent_value like 'ABC' order by usr.usr_login,ENT_DISPLAY_NAME;
   ```
3. Role and Access Policy mapping

   ```
   select pol.pol_name, poc.poc_field_value from pol, poc where poc.pol_key  = pol.pol_key AND poc.poc_field_name = 'ABC' order by pol.pol_name, poc.poc_field_value
   ```
4. To check Role assigned to User

   ```
   select usr.usr_login, ugp.ugp_name from usg usg left outer join usr usr on (usg.usr_key = usr.usr_key) 
       left outer join ugp ugp on (ugp.ugp_key = usg.ugp_key) 
   where ugp_name ='ABC'
   ```

Comment: For Role and access policy mapping, here's an alternative query -
`Select POL_NAME,ugp.ugp_display_name  "ROLE" from POL, UGP where pol.pol_owner=ugp.ugp_key;`